# How to run variable number of methods depending on user input in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, background

I am struggling with the concept described below:

User checks x of 5 checkboxes with type of measurements and then he clicks "RUN".
On the "RUN" OnClick() I create a Measure class object.

```
class Measure
{
    string measure_type;
    SendCommandToArduino(string nameOfMeasurement)
    ...
}
```

**I need to run those selected methods IN SEQUENCE (they CANNOT run asynchronous, because they use Serial COM).**

I hardcoded something like this:

```
void Method1()
{
    measurement.SendCommandToArduino("tetnienie");
}

void Method2()
{
    measurement.SendCommandToArduino("jasnosc");
}

tPomiar1 = new Thread(Method1);
tPomiar1.Start();
tPomiar1.Join();
pomiar.DrawGraphTetnien(tetnienie_Chart);
tPomiar2 = new Thread(Method2);
tPomiar2.Start();
tPomiar2.Join();
MessageBox.Show("Done all measurements!");
```

No surprise - it worked. But:

1. I still don't know how to relate number of checked checkboxes with number of methods to run in these threads. Maybe I should hardcode MethodX for all measurements and then run threads from some List list_of_threads?
2. Threads are overkill for this purpose ( I guess ), cause the longest measurement takes about 10 seconds... Is there any other way?
   ThreadPool, Tasks, async/await ? I am totally new to multi-tasking/threading

I also tried something like this, but I didn't finish this solution, it was too hardcore:

```
    List<Thread> list_of_threads= new List<Thread>();
    List<Action> measureToDo = new List<Action>();
    // link those additions with checkboxes
    measureToDo.Add(Method1);
    measureToDo.Add(Method2);
    measureToDo.Add(Method3);

    int i = 0;
    foreach (Action action in measureToDo)
    {
        //substring this one to get method's name!
        string methodName = action.Method.Name.ToString());
        methodName = methodName.Substring(4,6) // limit of 9 methods here haha
    }

    foreach (var item in measureToDo )
    {
        RunThread(item.Method.Name.ToString());
    }

    void RunThread(Action a)
    {
        Thread t;

        t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(a.Method.Name)).Start();
    }
```

---

For a measure_type I created a '5-bit' string -> Containg "1" if the checkbox on this position was checked.
"01000" / "10011" etc.

Thank You in advance for all hints/tips! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are overcomplicating things, and a simple solution would be perfectly well.

You can use `Control.Tag` property and add the name (as string) of the measure to everyone of your checkboxes.  Then, you can enumerate your check-boxes, see which is checked, and get a list of strings with the names of the measures you need to perform.

Then, you need a single method to execute your measures.  It should enumerate the list, and have a switch to map a measure to a method:

```
void ExecuteMeasures(List<string> measures) 
{
    foreach (string measure in measures)
    {
        switch (measure)
        {
            case "Measure 1": MeasureMethodOne(); break;
            // and so on...
        }
     }
 }
```

Then you don't need to run each measure method in a separate thread, because you want them to be executed sequentially.  You only need to run the ExecuteMeasureMethod in a separate thread.  Having it run for seconds, a separate thread is fine.  Still, to keep things neat, use a long running task:

```
var listOfMeasures = new List<string>();
//Populate your list from the selection of check boxes
Task t = Task.StartNew ( ()=> ExecuteMeasures(listOfMeasures), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
await t;
```

Comment: this one works, but I coudn't just add "await t" (last line)

Comment: You need to label your method as async.  I recommend you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: well, I just used t.Wait() :>

Comment: `t.Wait()` is not great, because it blocks your IU.

Comment: well, that's a fact indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
1. Define a Action array to store your methods
2. Get the values of checked items(checkbox1's value is 0, etc.) as the array indices
3. Invoke the relevant method in the array.

Codes are something like :

```
public static void Main()
{
    Action[] actions = new Action[5];
    actions[0] = Method1;
    actions[1] = Method2;

    string checkedValue = "1";
    actions[int.Parse(checkedValue) - 1].Invoke();
}

static void Method1()
{
    Console.WriteLine(1);
}

static void Method2()
{ }
```

Or you can simplify the code as below:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Action[] actions = new Action[5];
    actions[0] = ()=> { Console.WriteLine(1); };
    actions[1] = ()=> { Console.WriteLine(2); };

    string checkedValue = "1";
    actions[int.Parse(checkedValue) - 1].Invoke();
}
```